# Cut Law For Abjunction

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Considering the signature $\Sigma = \{\nrightarrow\}$, incorporated in  Hilbert Calculus, $\mathcal{H}_{abj}= \langle \Sigma, R \rangle$, and the corresponding logic $\mathcal{L}_{abj} = \langle \Sigma, \ \_^{\vdash} \rangle$, where the set $R$ holds as rules:
$$ \frac{p \nrightarrow q}{p} $$
$$\frac{ p \nrightarrow q \quad  q}{r} $$
$$ \frac{p \quad r \nrightarrow q}{p \nrightarrow q} $$

I want to prove that the Cut Law applys, i.e. given $\Gamma \subseteq L_{\Sigma}(P)$ :
$$ \frac{\Gamma \vdash A
\\ \Gamma, \ B \vdash \varphi
\\ \Gamma, \ A \nrightarrow B \vdash \varphi}{ \Gamma \vdash \varphi} $$

How shall I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

1) $\Gamma \vdash A$ --- premise

2) $\Gamma , B \vdash \varphi$ --- premise

3) $\Gamma, A \nrightarrow B \vdash \varphi$ --- premise

By the "intuitive" reading of [Abjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_nonimplication), we have that from 1) and 3):

4) $\Gamma, \lnot B \vdash \varphi$

Thus, with a form of [Excluded Middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_systems#Implication_and_negation): "if $\Gamma, \lnot B \vdash \varphi$ and $\Gamma, B \vdash \varphi$, then $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$" [corresponding to the tautology: $\vDash (B \to A) \to ((\lnot B \to A) \to A)$], we have:

> 5) $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ --- from 2) and 4).

---

What other rules are available in order to have:

> $A, \lnot B \vdash A \nrightarrow B$ ?

With "standard" rules for $\to$ and $\lnot$ we may derive it by contradiction: assume $A, \lnot B$ and $A \to B$ and derive the contradiction $B \land \lnot B$, concluding with $\lnot (A \to B)$.

But can we derive $A \nrightarrow B$ from $\lnot (A \to B)$ ?